# How can I change the console resolution on a CentOS 6.2 server?

Tags: centos, centos6

How can I change the console resolution on a CentOS 6.2 server?

Answer (score 3):

Adding the following to end of the kernel line in your grub.conf

```
vga=791
```

will increase your console resolution to 1024x768.

Other possible values can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VESA_BIOS_Extensions#Linux_video_mode_numbers)

Answer (score 1):

If by console you mean Gnome Terminal, then you can change the size in the View menu or with the keys CTRL + and CTRL -. If you mean your ssh console when accessing the server remotely, then it depends on the software you're using. Check its documentation. Either way, this is something rather trivial that don't belong in this forum.